# como puedo hacer repetir un switch case con el do while infinitamente

Tags: c++, bucles

Como podría hacer como especie de un bucle infinito hasta que el mismo usuario quiera salir con unas de las opciones.

```
//cajero virtual

#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int saldo_inicial=5000, opcion, ingreso=0, retiro=0,saldo=0;
    
        
    cout<<"\n\n\t\tBienvenido a su cajero virtual"<<endl;

    cout<<"1. Ingresar saldo"<<endl;
    cout<<"2. retirar saldo"<<endl;
    cout<<"3. Salir"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\tDigite su opcion"<<endl;
    cin>>opcion;
        
    switch(opcion){
        
        case 1: cout<<"\nDigite la cantidad a ingresar: "<<endl; cin>>ingreso;
                saldo = saldo_inicial + ingreso;
                
                cout<<"Operacion exitosa, saldo actual: "<<saldo; break;
                
        case 2: cout<<"Digite la cantidad a retirar: "; cin>>retiro;
                saldo= saldo_inicial - retiro;
                
                if(retiro>saldo_inicial){
                    cout<<"Saldo insuficiente"<<endl;
                }
                else{
                    cout<<"Operacion exitosa, saldo actual: "<<saldo; break;
                }
                
        case 3: break;
                    
    }       
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Con que pongas el do antes del primer cout, y un while con la condición de opción distinto a 3 es suficiente...

Comment: Por eso el while distinto de 3...

Answer (score 1):

Algo así funcionaría:

```
//cajero virtual

#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int saldo_inicial=5000, opcion, ingreso=0, retiro=0,saldo=0;

    cout<<"\n\n\t\tBienvenido a su cajero virtual"<<endl;

    do{
        cout<<"1. Ingresar saldo"<<endl;
        cout<<"2. retirar saldo"<<endl;
        cout<<"3. Salir"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t\tDigite su opcion"<<endl;
        cin>>opcion;
            
        switch(opcion){
            case 1: cout<<"\nDigite la cantidad a ingresar: "<<endl; cin>>ingreso;
                    saldo = saldo_inicial + ingreso;
                    cout<<"Operacion exitosa, saldo actual: "<<saldo; 
                break;
                    
            case 2: cout<<"Digite la cantidad a retirar: "; cin>>retiro;
                    saldo= saldo_inicial - retiro;
                    if(retiro>saldo_inicial){
                        cout<<"Saldo insuficiente"<<endl;
                    }
                    else{
                        cout<<"Operacion exitosa, saldo actual: "<<saldo;
                    }
                break;//El break no debe estar dentro de un if o else, si no al final
                    
            case 3: break;          
        }       
        getch();
    }while(opcion != 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Otra opción sería hacer un `while(true)` y terminar la aplicación al pulsar el 3